# Port binding on macos

Tags: java, sockets, osx-server

I used ServerSocket in java to check whether the mysql is running or not . If it's not running I prompted the user to please run your mysql server . But , Some of my users complained we got error message although the mysql is running . It only happens in macos . What I find is .

Java Code :

```
public static boolean isPortFree(int port)
{
    if(port <= 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    ServerSocket sock = null;
    try
    {
        String bindAddress = System.getProperty("bindaddress", "127.0.0.1");
        sock = new ServerSocket(port,0,InetAddress.getByName(bindAddress));
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (sock != null)
        {
            try
            {
                sock.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

If i set system property `bindaddress` to `localhost` it returns false  same i set to `127.0.0.1` returns true . 
localhost , 127.0.0.1 is same why it behaves like this . It only occurs in macos . I think it's not a `my.cnf` bindaddress problem . Because I checked in command prompt with

```
 mysql -uroot -hlocalhost
 mysql -uroot -h127.0.0.1
```

both are works .

**Netstat**

MacOs

```
 tcp4       0      0  *.3306                 *.*                    LISTEN
```

Other Os

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Is there any difference between tcp4 and tcp?

Any Idea why it happens ?

Comment: I don't understand why you are using `ServerSocket` for this in the first place. Just try to open a `Socket` to port 3306. If it succeeds, MySQL is running. If not, not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two examples are effectively binding to different interfaces: `INADDR_ANY` does not prevent binds to specific adapters.

It will work as expected if on OSX MySQL was configured exactly the same as your reported '*Other Os*'.